# Testing the difference between 2 Cox regression models

Tags: r, regression, anova, cox-model

I am running an ANOVA test on R comparing the results of 2 cox regression models. Model 1 has variableA (binary). Model 2 has the interaction term for variableA * variableB (3 categories).

I'm not sure to interpret the results. If the p-value is significant, does it mean that globally the 2 models are different? Or that at least one of the comparisons is different?

Thank you

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, regarding interaction, stick with model 2 and make sure you have included varA, varB, and varA*varB in the model.  When you are assessing the interaction between two variables you must include the "main effects", i.e., the two variables separately, plus the interaction term.

To test the difference of the two models, you could run the no-interaction model 1 with VarA and VarB, record the log-likelihood value (call this LLR, for "reduced model"), then run model 2 with VarA, VarB and VarA*VarB to get LLF ("full model").  Then, apply the log-likelihood ratio test to compare two models with different predictors.

The R-package you are using should be able to perform the log-likelihood ratio test between two models (with different predictors).

The significance will be based on the difference between LLF and LLF times a constant, compared to a critical value (look up) of chi-squared based on the difference in degrees of freedom (d.f.) between the two models.

ANOVA is for comparing means between 3 or more groups for one continuous outcome variable (SBP, weight, etc.) and is not used for time-to-event modeling like Cox PH regression.

**UPDATE**

Per @EdM's comment, the significant "ANOVA" test in R which performs the log-likehood ratio test would imply that adding the interaction term significantly improved the fit of the model.

Comment: There might be a bit of a terminological confusion here. Although "ANOVA" is classically considered to be as you describe, there is an `anova()` function in R, for example, that can do the likelihood-based comparison of nested models that you describe. I suspect that the latter is what the OP had in mind. That should give the same result as the nominal significance test for the `A:B` interaction term in the full model, provided that the "main effects" are included in the full model as you correctly insist upon. +1

Comment: Thanks @EdM - see the update.